# Back-transforming contrast lstrends results

Tags: r, transformation, mixed-models, lsmeans

I calculated a linear mixed model using the packages lme4 and lsmeans with the lmer-function, where I have one dependent variable rv and the interacting factors treatment, time, age, and race. I'm interested in the response variable change over time, that's why I use the lstrends-function. So far so good. The problem is, I have to square root the response variable in order to fit the model properly. But the pairs-function only gives out a response to the square root of the rv, hard to interpret!

So I tried to back-transform the response variable after pairs:

```
model.lmer <- lmer(sqrt(rv) ~ treat*time*age*race + (1|individual), data=mydata)
model.lst <- lstrends(model.lmer, ~treat | age*race , var = "time", type="response")
pairs(mouse.lst, type="response")
```

This obviously doesn't work, as stated by the package itself:

```
# Transformed response
sqwarp.rg <- ref.grid(update(warp.lm, sqrt(breaks) ~ .))
summary(sqwarp.rg)

# Back-transformed results - compare with summary of 'warp.rg'
summary(sqwarp.rg, type = "response")

# But differences of sqrts can't be back-transformed
summary(pairs(sqwarp.rg, by = "wool"), type = "response")

# We can do it via regrid
sqwarp.rg2 <- regrid(sqwarp.rg)
summary(sqwarp.rg2)  # same as for sqwarp.rg with type = "response"
pairs(sqwarp.rg2, by = "wool")
```

It could look like the following code:

```
summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~ treat | race*age, trend="time")), type="response")
```

The problem is, I can't alter the reference grid for lstrends, just for lsmeans, because the first argument in lstrends or lsmeans with trend="time" requires the linear mixed effect model (model.lmer) intead of just the reference grid like in lsmeans, without the trend-argument... That's probably why I can't back-transform the data with

This here sums up my problem pretty well:

```
model.sqrt <- lmer(sqrt(rv) ~ time*treat*race*age, data=mydata)
rg <- ref.grid(model.sqrt)
rg.regrid <- regrid(rg)
summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~treat | race*age*time), type = "response"))
```

Works perfectly.

```
summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~treat | race*age, trend="time"), type = "response"))
```

Gives the following error:

```
Error in summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~vns | gen * age, trend = "time"),  : 
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': Error in data[[var]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How to avoid the error and still be able to back-transform my data?

Answer (score 0):

It does NOT seem to seem possible at all - the back-transformation would be a complicated procedure without any obvious pattern. That's what the creator of the package said.

Comment: was that a personal communication (e.g. e-mail), or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It was a personal communication, but there are small hints in the lsmeans-documentation itself:

"Note: lstrends computes a difference quotient based on two slightly different reference grids.
Thus, it must be called with a model object, not a ref.grid object."

That's why my last approach under edit2 didn't work.

Mathematically spoken, it's also clear that it would not be an easy transformation, so this already foreshadowed that it would not work.

Comment: Note - I posted an answer to this on Cross Validated -- http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228958/back-transforming-contrast-lstrends-results-in-r/229847#229847